# Why does IKEv2 fail on Windows 8 and Android strongSwan, but not on Windows 7?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I'm trying to allow Windows and Android clients to connect through a VPN to a Windows Server 2012 Essentials machine. The VPN works fine over SSTP, but for [performance reasons](https://serverfault.com/questions/434425/setting-up-a-vpn-on-windows-2008-r2-should-i-use-pptp-or-sstp/434447#comment485927_434447), I want to move to IKEv2.

IKEv2 works on a Windows 7 client, but on Windows 8 clients and the Android strongSwan client, the server responds with `Error 13819: Invalid certificate type`. I've copied the VPN connection from the Windows 7 client over to a Windows 8 client, to make sure the connections are identical, but no joy.

The server's certificate has the Server Authentication and IKE intermediate EKUs specified. Although I thought it might be a error in how the server certificate is set up, I now suspect that this may turn out to be a client configuration problem, rather than a server configuration one.

As far as I can see, since I'm using EAP-MSCHAPv2 to authenticate clients, I shouldn't need any client authentication certificate on the clients, but I suspect that the server is somehow expecting one.